# Is there a way to input a variable (such as x) into my calculator for use with integrals or derivatives?

Tags: calculus, calculator

There is a button on my calculator dedicated to derivatives and integrals, but I've never been able to use it because I don't know how to represent a variable (it seems the only thing I can derive or integrate with respect to is x, i.e. the operator reads $d/dx$).

As it turns out, there is an "x" button on my calculator, but for whatever reason it seems to represent a constant with the value of 24.8...no idea where that comes from, and using it as normal in a derivative or integral does not work (gives a syntax error).

Here is a picture of my calculator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KJU3.jpg

Any ideas at all are appreciated!

Comment: Possible suggestion: based on what I can see, there's an "$x$" above the "$)$" (which you'd input with Alpha $\to$ "$)$"). Perhaps that?

Comment: The Casio website has the [manual for your calculator](https://support.casio.com/en/manual/manualfile.php?cid=004009138).  Instructions for using the $\frac{d}{dx}$ key appear on page 15.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer it seems like that's it, somehow completely missed that x, thank you so much!

Comment: @FredH Didn't think of that, thank you!